# It does not take changes when generating publication files. Angular 8

Tags: angular, iis

I have a project in `angular 8` and `C #  WebApi` which I publish on an `IIS` server, up to this point all right, when I made the first publication there was no problem but At the time of making changes to my application and returning to generate the files, say when publishing Version 2, it does not take the changes made in my `Angular FrontEnd` when entering the application, it only does so when I reload the page with **`ctrl + R`**.

This is a big problem for users who use the application because if they do not reload they will continue working on the first version.

This is the way I generate the files:

**`ng build --prod --output-hashing = all`**

This line generates the following files:

[image]

I have these lines of code in the `index.html`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

I don't know what happens but only take the new version only if the page is reloaded that way.

I would like it to clean and force and cache when generating the files.

Is there any way to do this from code or when generating files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if your browser has accessed your web application once, it will store the cache in client side.

If you modify the content and add the response header, it will not re-send the request to the server, it will use the cache page.

To aovid this, the only way is clear the browser's cache or use Ctrl+F5 to refresh the page.
Then if your response header contains the no-cache next time, the browser will not store the cache again.